# Deduce transfer function in a mechanical network

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring, oscillators

I am familiar with a 2 degree-of-freedom (2DOF) system like it is depicted here: [image: 2DOF system]

Assume all parameters are unknown. Now, how do I find the values of the parameters in case of

A) a spring and damper between m1 and m2 (like shown),
 B) an unknown combination of springs and dampers between m1 and m2.
 C) a general non-linear transfer function between m1 and m2.

Can I read out the transfer function, specifically the one between m1 and m2 (in every case)  - how do I do it?

My considerations go into the following direction: I am able to introduce a driving force at either m1 or m2 and read at the same time either x1 or x2 out. That gives me a system of equations (Driving: m1, Reading: x2 - Driving m1, Reading x1 - Driving m2 etc.)

But how would an unknown shape of the response function (especially in case C) be incorporated in the equations of motion. That is: assuming, I have no idea what is in between m1 and m2, how do I formally write that down in order to then write down all the different response functions and then solve for the unknown thing in between m1 and m2.

cheers
G